# google test PrintTo for std::set<std::string>

Tags: c++, googletest

In the google test [Advanced documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#teaching-googletest-how-to-print-your-values) they say to write `PrintTo` in the same namespace that defines the value to be printed, which is great if it's your own class in your own namespace, but if it's `std::set` you aren't supposed to add new members to namespace `std`.

So how do you customize the `PrintTo` behavior for `std::set<std::string>`?  The default printer in google test stops printing after a certain number of values which isn't useful when the values that differ come after the ones emitted by the default printer.

```
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

void PrintTo(const std::set<std::string> &value, std::ostream *str)
{
    *str << "Got here!\n";
}

TEST(MapPrint, custom_printer)
{
    std::set<std::string> one{"foo"};
    std::set<std::string> two{"bar"};

    ASSERT_EQ(one, two); // doesn't print 'Got here!'
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "you aren't supposed to"? Are you looking for a solution that avoid doing that for stylistic reasons, or are you saying that it is not valid (it is).

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std "It is undefined behavior to add declarations or definitions to namespace std or to any namespace nested within std, with a few exceptions noted below".  In addition to being undefined behavior, it still doesn't select my `PrintTo` implementation, even when in namespace `std`.

Comment: Correction: it does work in namespace `std` (I had the wrong container type in my test I was working from), but it is still undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, you are right, I didn't check the C++ standard. I only tested the code with namespace std and it gave me the right output, so I assumed it was fine.

Comment: For own types it works to overload either `<<` or the implicit conversion to `std::string_view`, whereas the latter seems to take precedence.
I don't know how to "hook" into before that conversion for `std::set`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What works is to define `PrintTo` in namespace `testing::internal`.  This still feels a little dirty to me.  Presumably the `internal` namespace is so that google test can change whatever implementation details they like in there without regard to backwards compatibility.  At least it doesn't result in undefined behavior as would defining `PrintTo` in namespace `std`.